# What type of isomerism relates an allene from a conjugated diene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

What type of isomerism exist between an isolated/conjugated diene and a cummulated diene (allene)? Are they functional isomers or position isomers?

For example, are buta-1,3-diene and buta-1,2-diene functional or positional isomers? My one chemistry teacher is saying functional and another positional!

Comment: They are just what they are. The classification into functional and positional isomers exists only in our heads.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about buta-1,2-diene and buta-1,3-diene, I'd say they are both. They are functional group isomers, because I consider an allene to be a distinct functional group from a conjugated diene. Others might not see it this way, but they have different chemistry and considerations.

They are positional isomers, because they only differ by the position of a group (in this case a hydrogen / pi-bond).

I don't see the need for it to be one or the other and not both.

However, the more important classification is that they are *constitutional isomers* (or structural isomers). That is, they differ in the connectivity of atoms. This is in comparison to stereoisomers, that have the same connectivity but different spatial arrangements of atoms.